# Obtener ID de Botones

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

estoy haciendo una app donde inserto programaticamente una serie de botones, este es mi código y lo genera perfectamente bien. Donde tengo dudas es como obtener el id de cada botón y mostrar un msj de que se ha hecho clic sobre dicho botón espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

```
Button boton = new Button(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout mlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mlayout.addView(row);
    }
    setContentView(mlayout);

    boton.setOnClickListener(myClickBtn);
}

View.OnClickListener myClickBtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
    int position = (int) boton.getId();

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boton 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boton 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                // it was the second button
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boton 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar un `Button` de manera dinámica a un `ViewGroup`, debes crear el `Button` y asignar los parámetros del layout que sean del tipo de quien lo contiene. Según estoy viendo, estas creando varios `LinearLayout`, no `Button` en tu código.

```
LinearLayout mlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mlayout.addView(row);
}
```

Este código anterior hace que crees un `LinearLayout` como `root` que va a contener 3 `LinearLayouts` hijos. Ahora bien, si por cada fila (porque el padre definio orientacion vertical), quieres agregar un boton, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
LinearLayout mlayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
mlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Cada fila va a tener un contenedor hijo `LinearLayout` que a su vez va a contener un `Button`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    Button btnInRow = new Button(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lllp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lllp);
    btnInRow.setLayoutParams(lllp);
    btnInRow.setId(/* Aqui agregas cualquier entero positivo */);
    btnInRow.setOnClickListener(myClickBtn);
    row.addView(btnInRow);
    mlayout.addView(row);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que al no asignarle `orientation` a `row`, estas definiendo la orientacion **horizontal** por default. Puedes agregar cualquier propiedad del objeto `Button` con la referencia de `btnInRow`, **texto**, **color**, **etc**...

Ahora vamos al caso. El `id` de una vista es un identificador de la misma, no representa la posición en el `Layout` que quieres. Por lo que al hacer click e intentar obtener el id, a menos que hayas hecho un `setId` con el caso especificado, tomara la sentencia como verdadera o falsa en el `switch/case`. El id del boton, debe ser unico para el root, pero puede ser igual a otras referencias de id, siempre y cuando dos vistas no tengan el mismo id en un root. Esto quiere decir, que no debes setear el mismo id, en el ciclo por ejemplo, para las 3 vistas creadas, ya que no podrás tomar la referencia correcta a la hora de buscarla en el `root` con el mismo **id**.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente si quieres representar una `posicion` en el `layout`, de cada vista creada:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    . . .
    btnInRow.setId(/* Aqui agregas cualquier entero positivo unico para el root (no obligatorio)*/);
    btnInRow.setTag(i); // donde i representa la posicion
    btnInRow.setOnClickListener(myClickBtn);

    . . .
}
```

y en tu `onClick` obtienes el Click del boton con el **id** si es que tienes un arreglo global o una referencia a los ids creados, como una lista o el **tag (la posicion)**:

```
View.OnClickListener myClickBtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
    int position = (int) boton.getTag();

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boton 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boton 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                // it was the second button
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Boton 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarse su tiempo en contestar, ya lo arregle tal como esta la propuesta sugerida, solo un detalle, de que forma podría manejar las coordenadas de mis botones, para que no tomen la posición por defecto...

Comment: @JavierIrepan si te sirvio mi respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada (debajo del contador de votos de la respuesta hay una flecha de aceptacion). Ahora bien, si te refieres a posicionar el boton, centrarlo, ajustarlo al principio, o al final de su contenedor `row`, debes utilizar la propiedad del `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` que en el ejemplo se llama `lllp` llamada gravity. Por ejemplo `lllp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;` te daras cuenta que `Gravity` tiene mas variantes como START, END, etc... Ten en cuenta que esto debes hacerlo despues de asignarle los `LayoutParams` a `row`.

Comment: Si quieres asignar tamaños diferentes a tu boton. Puedes crear un LinearLayout.LayoutParams solo para el boton y asignarle un tamaño fijo en vez de MATCH_PARENT y WRAP_CONTENT o si quieres que se ajuste el tamaño del boton a su contenido, como por ejemplo al texto que contenga, puedes hacer WRAP_CONTENT tanto en el Width como en el Height. Ejemplo: `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

Answer (score -1):

Usa el metodo `getId()`. Retorna el id como un entero así que puedes compararlo con el id de los recursos.

It is very convenient to use switch statement like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.boton1:
            // accion
            break;
        case R.id.boton2:
            // accion
            break;
        case R.id.boton3:
            // accion
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que los botones son dinamicos, a menos que cree items de tipo id en un xml o defina dichos ids directamentes en el Layout, seria valido. Pero al crear una vista dinamica, no se crean con la propiedad id, por lo que tendria que hacerlo de manera manual.

Comment: navegando un poco en stackoverlow encontre esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658144/how-to-identify-the-button-clicked-from-a-dynamically-generated-table creo que resuelve tu problema

Answer (score -1):

Yo creo que lo mejor sería hacerlo con la clase `LayoutInflater`

```
View v = getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tu_xml, null);
```

..y si quieres manipular algun objeto view como es tu caso un Button.

```
Button b = v.findViewById(R.id.id_de_tu_boton);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), te sugiero completar el recorrido para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes ver la sección de [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tus respuestas sean bien recibidas.